# Why do elements of coprime orders commute in nilpotent groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to show the following statement:

---

Let $G$ be a nilpotent group and $a,b\in G$ such that there exist $m,n\in\mathbf{N}_{>0}$ such that $\text{gcd}(m,n)=1$ and $a^m=b^n=1$. Then $ab=ba$.

---

If $G$ is finite, this is clear to me, since I know that then $G$ is the direct product of its Sylow subgroups.

I have found a sketch of a proof in Hall's *Theory of groups*: If $G=G_1,G_2,\ldots$ is the lower central series of $G$, show that $[a,b]\in G_i$ for any $i$, which then implies $[a,b]=e$. Hall even gives another hint: If $[a,b]\in G_i$, show that $[a,b]^m\in G_{i+1}$ and $[a,b]^n\in G_{i+1}$. Unfortunately I can't do that. I managed the case $m=2$:
$$a^{-1}b^{-1}aba^{-1}b^{-1}ab=a^{-1}(b^{-1}a^{-1}ba)a(a^{-1}b^{-1}ab)=[a,[a,b]],$$
but I don't see how to generalize this.

Another hint would be nice.

Comment: Are you familiar with the commutator identities, like $[ab,c] = b^{-1}[a,c]b[b,c]$? They imply that, if $[a,b]$ is in the centre of the group, then $[a^k,b] = [a,b^k] = [a,b]^k$ for any $k$. Now you know that the image of $[a,b]$ in $G/G_{i+1}$ is in the centre of $G/G_{i+1}$ ...

Comment: @Stefan Walter This question is very close to this one http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36056/nilpotent-group-is-almost-abelian-counterexample-for-infinite-order-case

Comment: @Plop: And your answer there is the perfect answer to this question. Why I didn't realize this before, I don't know. Should this question be closed as a duplicate? Alternatively, I would also accept an answerification of Derek's comment. Thank you both!

Comment: @Derek: It seems like I can't notify two people in one comment. So I added this one.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to note that the finite groups $G$ having the property that for all $a, b \in G$ with $gcd(order(a), order(b))=1$, one has $order(ab)=order(a).order(b)$, are the nilpotent groups. 

In other words, for a finite group $G$ the order function is "multiplicative" iff $G$ is nilpotent.

Comment: How could one prove this? One only has to prove this for finite groups generated by two elements of coprime order, but I have no idea from here

Answer (score 1):

Since you are okay in the finite case, can you show that the subgroup generated by $a$ and $b$ is finite?

Comment: I'd be interested in how you would prove this. Do you have a concrete idea?

Comment: @James, I think you misunderstood, the theorem only holds for finite groups. I thought I was clear in stating that. So the subgroup generated by $a$ and $b$ is automatically finite.